# How to counter multiple Reinhardts

Tags: overwatch

While playing competitive with my friends last night, we encountered a team with 3 Reinhardts on Ilios. We were able to take two rounds, but they crushed us on the other three maps.

We tried anything we could think of; Bastion, Torbjorn, a Tracer to annoy them or break their line, but it was next to impossible.

Is there a good method to countering so many heavy shields without losing focus on the other three players?

Comment: Symmetra's right click goes right through Reinhardt shields.

Comment: How did u manage to fail with bastion ..... Bastion + someone to protect him would have been enough!

Comment: @Иво Недев Enemy team had 3 Reinhardts, a Tracer, Lucio, and Reaper. Tracer and Reaper would just melt anything static that we tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Bastion + a Reinhardt will melt through a Reinhardt shield, while giving him some longevity against Widowmakers and Pharahs. The rest of the team needs to stay near to take care of these pesky Tracers and Reapers that like to flank behind. A Bastion is most effective on the defensive, or on the cart as an offensive strategy.

To kill the Reinhardts, you can use Symmetra to deal damage through their shields. Since Reinhardts are slow when moving with their shield up, they can't really dodge it.

You can use McCree to flashbang a Reinhardt in the face. You need to bypass the shield, then DPS him down while he is stunned.

Use a Pharah to get above or behind the Reinhardts. Then apply a few rockets to the face.

Use a Hanzo and use scatter arrow and a wild dragon to kill the relatively immobile Reinhardts.

Use a Lúcio and simply blast them into the pit.

Use D'va's ability to pump out a continuous stream of damage without needing a reload to pressure the shield.

Use Junkrat's remote mine by throwing it through the shield, then detonating it to juggle one or more Reinhardts out of position. Then punish them for it.

---

The thing you have to keep in mind is that Reinhardt's main focus is to provide a directional shield. He can swing his hammer at close-range heroes, blast someone in the distance once in a while and charge at the enemy. His DPS is low, and so is his ability to move.

Use abilities that abuse this fact. Mobile heroes can flank. A Reinhardt cannot defend himself from attacks from two different angles. Heavy damage heroes such as Bastion can break anything if it comes close.

Comment: I really don't know why we didn't think of Pharah. Hanzo is tough because unless he does damage with his arrow, his charge won't increase, so while his ability is awesome, it wouldn't really help here. Lucio was my role, but I've been having a lot of inconsistencies with how far people get knocked back.

Comment: Totally agree with this post, phara would have done it, for damage and/or for splitting them.
I would add the fact that playing reinhart is also great against multiple reinhart: If they are packed, try to go on them with reinhart. If you go in the middle of the 3 reinhardt, one of them has to quit shielding in order to attack you, if only one does you started hitting first and kill him, so two of them have to stop shielding, if they aren't coordinated enought, they'll be 3 to stop shield and easy to kill for your team.

Comment: Junkrat also does very respectable damage to Rein shields, and if you lob your mine over them, you can even break their turtle formation. Failing that, just Riptire past the shields and try and get one or two of them

Comment: Junkrat works against one reinhart, not against multiple if they are in the same formation, one still can have this shield up to protect from aerial. In fact, same does for phara but she still can split them as soon as they have to swap.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Note that Reinhardt's barrier blocks the knockback. That's troublesome.

Comment: Junkrat should be on the list mainly due to his remote mine.  His mine can be tossed though shields, but it's the knock-back effect that will break their phalanx. One of those Reinhardt would of needed to turn around and block the mine to prevent this from happening, but that's 1/3 of your problem peeled away at the moment.

Comment: @NBN-Alex I have added Junkrat.

Comment: @NBN-Alex His mine can go through shields? I've never paid explicit attention to this, but I assumed it did not.

Comment: yep yep! The concussive mine (SHIFT key) usually keeps traveling until it hits a surface. I've had it used against me while as Reinhardt while my shield was up and seen it tossed though my barrier.  On testing this, I was able to recreate the reaction but it comes with the consequence of pushing a Reinhardt right into your team. At that point, expect a "Bull in a china shop" situation.

Comment: Thanks for your input all, this definitely helps. We'll be trying this next time some trolls decide to use 3 Reinhardts!

Comment: actually, I'm thinking of the Bastion + Reinhardt + Mercy combo added with a McCree to guard their rear (counter flankers like Tracer, Genji and Reaper). Bastion melts Rein's shield and once 1-2 of them are down, they would be forced off the point and then the heavy DPS can come in to clean up. The only counter to this would be the the 3 Reins charging in and pinning all 3 of them but they'll probably die to bastion while charging. Besides, Mercy can always Rez them back up.